# Trying to use imblearn.pipeline with RandomOverSampler and DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am trying to set hyperparameters of DecisionTreeClassifiers using GridSearchCV, and because my data is unbalanced, i am trying to use imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler

dtpass = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
pipe1 = Pipeline([('sampling', RandomOverSampler()), ('class', dtpass)])

parameters = {'class__max_depth': range(3,7), 
          'class__ccp_alpha': np.arange(0, 0.001, 0.00025), 
          'class__min_samples_leaf' : [50]
         }

dt2 = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe1, 
               param_grid = parameters,
               n_jobs = 4,
              scoring = 'roc_auc'
)

dt2.fit(x, y)
```

This returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'RandomOverSampler' object has no attribute '_validate_data'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT: Solution posted below**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np

dtpass = DecisionTreeClassifier()
sampling=RandomOverSampler()


pipe1=make_pipeline(sampling,dtpass)
# pipe1 = Pipeline([('sampling', RandomOverSampler()), ('class', dtpass)])

parameters = {'class__max_depth': range(3,7), 
          'class__ccp_alpha': np.arange(0, 0.001, 0.00025), 
          'class__min_samples_leaf' : [50]
         }

dt2 = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe1, 
               param_grid = parameters,
               n_jobs = 4,
              scoring = 'roc_auc'
)

dt2.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your response inspired me to take different approaches, which led me to drill down to the main problem. The solution was to re-install imbalanced package.

Comment: Yes, I suspected something was wrong on your end as I didn't face your error. Instead I found `RandomOverSampler` was not compatible with `Pipeline` object from `sklearn` as it doesn't has `fit`, `transform` methods. So I used  imblearn's `make_pipeline` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the solution page that took a *lot* of googling:

https://makerspace.aisingapore.org/community/ai4i-5-supervised-learning/encountered-attributeerror-when-run-train_test_splitpreprocessed_data-output_var-after-randomoversampler/

The solution was to

```
 pip install -U imbalanced-learn
```

instead of

```
 conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```